# How search for files using regex in linux shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell, search

Suppose, I want to search for files having python in filename in it, in all sub directories of linux, from a shell script. How can I search in all locations using regex?

Comment: [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is one. you can also use [find](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Find all .py files.

```
find / -name '*.py'
```

Find files with the word "python" in the name.

```
find / -name '*python*'
```

Same as above but case-insensitive.

```
find / -iname '*python*'
```

Regex match, more flexible. Find both .py files and files with the word "python" in the name.

```
find / -regex '.*python.*\|.*\.py'
```

Comment: @Milimetric If you don't have the quotes then the shell tries to interpret the wildcard. We want find to handle the wildcard, not the shell, so the `*` must be quoted.

Comment: Here can I use all Perl type regexes, like look forward, look behind, named group capture, etc?

Comment: because `-iname` is mentioned here: it might be useful to also mention `-iregex` which will do the same as `-regex` but case-insensitive (like `-iname`)

Comment: I wish there was a way to match a regex by file name but not the full path name.

Comment: To find only filename, not the full path, append `[^/]*` to the expression.

Answer (score -3):

If simple shell regexps will suffice, then you can use find

```
find /linux -name "*python*"
```

Otherwise, I'd say use ack (http://betterthangrep.com/)

Comment: Wildcards are not regular expressions, also not "simple shell regexps". In regular expressions, there is no `*` wildcard, but `*` is a quantifier.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `ack` changes some behaviour that heavy grep users are used to (e.g. putting the filename on a different line to the text match). That's enough of a barrier for me to give up on it.

Answer (score -5):

```
find / -name "python"
```

[filler text to meet min.]

Comment: That doesn't do regexp matching of filenames